# gRpc, client getting io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method even when the message is received and deserialized by the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, grpc

I'm new to gRpc, I'm trying to use it between a Java 11(Spring Boot 2) server  and a Java 8 (Spring Boot 1.5) client using gRpc 1.27.1 and protobuf 3.11.

Here is my setup:

I have data model library with just 1 proto definition file and maven files to generate java source code that is shared between the client and the server

The *relevant* parts of the `pom.xml`:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <grpcVersion>1.27.1</grpcVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <protocArtifact>
            com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.4:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
          </protocArtifact>
          <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
          <pluginArtifact>
            io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.27.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
          </pluginArtifact>
          <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compile-custom</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Snippets of server pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <grpcVersion>1.27.1</grpcVersion>
        <local.repository.folder>${pom.basedir}/lib/</local.repository.folder>
    </properties>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <!-- Java 9+ compatibility -->
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
                <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
                <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
                <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
<!-- For the server (only) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

The relevant parts of the client project pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <local.repository.folder>${pom.basedir}/lib/</local.repository.folder>
    <grpcVersion>1.27.1</grpcVersion>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>

<!-- This is the data model protobuf project -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>e2log</groupId>
      <artifactId>nsub-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- This is the service definition protobuf project -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>e2log</groupId>
      <artifactId>e2log-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
      <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
      <version>${grpcVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- There are a ton of other dependencies here that i am omitting for brevity-->
```

My service has just one very simple rpc definition for now:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "E2logData.proto";
option java_multiple_files = true;
package e2log.nsub.bridge;

service EventBridgeService {
    rpc RfqNotification( e2log.api.RfqNotificationEvent ) returns ( RfqNotificationResponse ) {}
}

message RfqNotificationResponse{
    bool relay_message = 1;
    e2log.api.RfqNotificationEvent request = 2;
}
```

The relevant parts of the client implementation which is in a in class annotated as a Spring `@Component`:

```
 // Connection with gRpc server
 @PostConstruct
  void init(){
    channel = nSubConnection();
    log.info("Established NSub gRpc connection for address={} with max-retries={}.", nsubServer, nSubMaxRetryAttempts);
    eventBridgeSvcBlockingStub = EventBridgeServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
  }
  

  @VisibleForTesting
  ManagedChannel nSubConnection() {
    return ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(nsubServer )
                                .enableRetry()
                                .maxRetryAttempts(nSubMaxRetryAttempts)
                                .usePlaintext() // for now until it works
                                .build();
  }


// Actual gRpc call
@EventListener
  public void nSubBridge(RfqEvent event){
    val wireEvent = rfqEventMapper.map(event);
    val resp = eventBridgeSvcBlockingStub.rfqNotification( wireEvent);
   //
   System.err.println(resp);
  }
```

Everything compiles and starts up just fine, when the client makes a call to the server, the server receives the call and prints out the received email address sent in the payload serialized as protbuf  by the client.
However right after the message is printed out on the server I get an error from on the client side 1st, then an error on the server side.

1. Client error:

```
ndler | Not auditing event RfqAwardedEvent for RFQ 1023-2020 action=false, user=true
23:26:00.193 | ERROR | c.e.s.i.LoginServiceImpl | error in handleException :: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method e2log.nsub.bridge.EventBridgeService/RfqNotification is unimplemented
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method e2log.nsub.bridge.EventBridgeService/RfqNotification is unimplemented
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:240)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:221)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:140)
    at e2log.nsub.bridge.EventBridgeServiceGrpc$EventBridgeServiceBlockingStub.rfqNotification(EventBridgeServiceGrpc.java:169)
    at com.e2log.rfq.event.RfqEventHandler.nSubBridge(RfqEventHandler.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at com.e2log.service.impl.PreawardToAwardTransition.notifyLspAndShipper(PreawardToAwardTransition.java:124)
    at com.e2log.service.impl.PreawardToAwardTransition.preAwardedToAwarded(PreawardToAwardTransition.java:75)
    at com.e2log.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.customerPreAwardedtoAward(CustomerServiceImpl.java:545)
    at com.e2log.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c32e4446.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
    at com.e2log.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eee40a0b.customerPreAwardedtoAward(<generated>)
    at com.e2log.controller.CustomerController.customerPreAwardedtoAward(CustomerController.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.e2log.exception.BadRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(BadRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at com.e2log.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthenticationFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at io.micrometer.spring.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

2. Server error:

```
2020-03-26 16:47:57.218  INFO 90080 --- [           main] e2log.nsub.NSubApp                       : Started NSubApp in 4.789 seconds (JVM running for 5.212)
test.eamil@mailinator.com
2020-03-26 18:26:00.189 ERROR 90080 --- [ault-executor-0] io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor     : Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed@2110c8d4

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream was terminated by error, no further calls are allowed
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:511) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:345) ~[grpc-stub-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at e2log.nsub.bridge.impl.EventBridgeService.rfqNotification(EventBridgeService.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at e2log.nsub.bridge.EventBridgeServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(EventBridgeServiceGrpc.java:217) ~[nsub-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:172) ~[grpc-stub-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onHalfClose(Contexts.java:86) ~[grpc-api-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:331) ~[grpc-core-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:817) ~[grpc-core-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.27.1.jar:1.27.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Any idea of what is going wrong with my client code or setup ?

Comment: Intellij wasted couple of hours of my time by adding super()!

Comment: And if you're using Spring, make sure you add the correct `@Service` (or similar) annotation to actually instantiate the binding class... oops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I had not posted my server code and that is where the problem was.

I'll post my mistake here so that no one else has to spend time with this silly mistake:

```
@Override
public void newRfqNotification(RfqNotificationEvent request, StreamObserver<RfqNotificationResponse> responseObserver) {
    
    super.newRfqNotification(request, responseObserver);

    
   /*

    My business logic to process the incoming request omitted.

   */

}
```

The call to `super.newRfqNotification()` above had been created when I invoked IntelliJ's `[Override Methods... ^O]` to create a template method for me to fill in with business logic.

I somehow started to write my business logic without deleting the call to super which is good in many cases but catastrophic in this case.
So what happens is that the super method processes normally and sends an answer to the client saying that the method has not been implemented and continues with the business logic written after the call to super().
See the implementations below:

Generated method(super):

```
    /**
     */
    public void newRfqNotification(e2log.api.RfqNotificationEvent request,
        io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<e2log.nsub.bridge.RfqNotificationResponse> responseObserver) {
      asyncUnimplementedUnaryCall(getNewRfqNotificationMethod(), responseObserver);
    }
```

Which calls:

```
/**
   * Sets unimplemented status for method on given response stream for unary call.
   *
   * @param methodDescriptor of method for which error will be thrown.
   * @param responseObserver on which error will be set.
   */
  public static void asyncUnimplementedUnaryCall(
      MethodDescriptor<?, ?> methodDescriptor, StreamObserver<?> responseObserver) {
    checkNotNull(methodDescriptor, "methodDescriptor");
    checkNotNull(responseObserver, "responseObserver");
    responseObserver.onError(Status.UNIMPLEMENTED
        .withDescription(String.format("Method %s is unimplemented",
            methodDescriptor.getFullMethodName()))
        .asRuntimeException());
  }
```

So then the client receives the `Status.UNIPLEMENTED` response and closes the stream which then leads to the server error.

Comment: It is a general convention to call super(), that's why you/I did not delete it.  Looks like Intellij followed that convension - and grpc design uses that to say "unimplemented". Bad.  Perhaps grpc must remove this "feature" that wastes people's time instead of helping.